# Extracting array data from JSONB column in PostgreSQL and Marshaling it to slice of string In Go using pgx library

Tags: postgresql, go, jsonb, pgx

I somehow managed to make this works , but not exactly as intended.
Code below is "poco" for data in JSONB column.

```
type post struct {
    Title       string   `json:"title"`
    Tags        []string `json:"tags"`
}
```

Below i have initialization of slice of posts as well as single post for scaning each row into. The rest is standard query code.
This 
`data` is column name that is declared as jsonb

```
var t post
var h []post
rows, err := conpool.Query("SELECT data FROM post")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    if err := rows.Scan(&t); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    h = append(h, t)
}
for _, v := range h {
    fmt.Println(v.Title,v.Tags)
}
```

Output i get:

```
First Title [qwe asd]
Second Title [qwe asd]
Third Title [qwe asd]
```

As you can see above , output of each tag slice is the same , since slice is just a pointer to underlying array last one that get pulled out of db overwrites previous ones. I know that if i declare post as `Tags [2]string` it works , but i need to use slice since i have no idea how many tags there might be, any suggestion for this problem?

This is what table looks like

```
1 | {"tags": ["asd", "dsa"], "title": "First Title"}
2 | {"tags": ["tsa", "asd"], "title": "Second Title"}
3 | {"tags": ["qwe", "asd"], "title": "Third Title"}
```

Comment: Declare `t` inside the `for` loop, not outside of it, that way you get a new instance per iteration. (https://play.golang.com/p/GdFOFNSt5ug)

Comment: Thanks , i get it.